# Exception during initialization of a CodeRefactoringProvider when trying to import DTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, mef, vsix

I am building a custom code refactoring provider as an extension to Visual Studio 2017 and I want it to access the `DTE` service. To get it I use the `ImportingConstructorAttribute` and declare the service a parameter:

```
[ExportCodeRefactoringProvider( LanguageNames.CSharp, Name = nameof( MyCodeRefactoringProvider ) )]
[Shared]
internal class MyCodeRefactoringProvider : CodeRefactoringProvider {
    private readonly DTE m_dte;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MyCodeRefactoringProvider( DTE dte ) {
        m_dte = dte;
    }

    public sealed override async Task ComputeRefactoringsAsync( CodeRefactoringContext context ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

However, when I run the provider in the Visual Studio experimental instance, the provider is not instantiated.

The refactoring provider works fine if I don't try to import the service provider. The same issue occurs if I use the `ImportAttribute` on a property instead of the `ImportingConstructorAttribute`.

There was also nothing in the ActivityLog.xml of Visual Studio.

How can I import `DTE` through MEF?

Comment: Did you try to import `IServiceProvider` instead of it implementation `SVsServiceProvider` and did you try to use directly `ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider` if you are referencing `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.*`?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria I tried to import `IServiceProvider`. The effect was that the extension was not loaded at all. I will check the global provider, but I would prefer to import it through MEF.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria: `ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider` does work, but I need an addititional reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0`, which I would like to avoid. SO I would strill prefer a MEF import.

Comment: Sorry, for the late response.Did your `ImportingConstructor` is `System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportingConstructor` or is it `System.Composition.ImportingConstructor` in the case when you try to import `SvcServiceProvider`?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria It is `System.ComponentModel.ImportingConstructorattribute`. I tried with `System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportConstructorAttribute` and `System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportAttribute`. Both didn't work. The provider was not created in both cases.

Comment: And it will not work, as I know, because `ExportCodeRefactoringProvider` exports as derived of `System.Composition.ExportAttribute` not as derived of `System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportAttribute`. I assume that this mechanism can import something, during the export custom implementation, only as `System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportAttribute`. I tried `System.Composition.ImportAttribute` and it just work, unlike `System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportAttribute`

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria: `System.Composition.ImportAttribute` does not work for me, I tried it again. Can you provide me with your code that is working?

Comment: Do you remember that `DTE` doesn't a part of MEF, unlike `SvsServiceProvider`? So [here a sample](https://pastebin.com/mUdL6dHA) that works for me.