# CodeRefactoringProvider makes Visual Studio not come back from "Gathering Suggestions" after obtaining DTE service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, vsix

I want to enumerate the current project's files form a custom `CodeRefactoringProvider` in a Visual Studio 2017 VSIX project. To do so, I get the `DTE` service with `Package.GetGlobalService` and iterate through the solution. This code looks like this:

```
[ExportCodeRefactoringProvider( LanguageNames.CSharp, Name = nameof( MyCodeRefactoringProvider ) )]
[Shared]
internal class MyCodeRefactoringProvider : CodeRefactoringProvider {
    public sealed override async Task ComputeRefactoringsAsync( CodeRefactoringContext context ) {
        await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync( cancellationToken );
        DTE dte = (DTE)Package.GetGlobalService( typeof( DTE ) );
        //Enumerate project items...
        return new CodeAction[ 0 ];
    }
}
```

I use `JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync` to access the `DTE` service from the main thread to avoid the related warning. I can enumerate the files and leave the `ComputeRefactoringsAsync` method. When I then try to open the refactoring popup menu, I get a message "Gathering Suggestions", which is constantly displayed until I press *Cancel*:

[image: Gathering Suggestions]

It is actually completely irrelevant if I actually use the `DTE` interface or add some actual `CodeAction` objects. Just obtaining the service is enough.

I have tried the following to fix the issue, without any luck:

1. I have removed the call to `SwitchToMainThreadAsync` (and ignored the warning). The message is still displayed.
2. I have tried to import the `DTE` interface through MEF, which doesn't work (as explained in [this  Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860813/exception-during-initialization-of-a-coderefactoringprovider-when-trying-to-impo))
3. I have tried to enumerate the project file in another thread that I have started with `JoinableTaskFactory.RunAsync`. And then call `JoinAsync` on the task. The issue still occurs.
4. I have tried to return to the original thread with `await TaskScheduler.Default`. No luck again.

Enumerating the files through the `CodeRefactoringContext` does not work in this case, because it only contains the C# files and I need to access other file types, too. I specifically need to access `resx` files. Through the context I get access to the source file generated from the resx, not to the file itself.

Is there a way to use `DTE` without this issue occurring? Or is there any other way to access the project items from a `CodeRefactoringProvider`?

Comment: There are other ways (`((VisualStudioWorkspace)context.Document.Project.Solution.Workspace).GetHierarchy(context.Document.Project.Id);`) but they will also need thread synchronization. Are you talking about the VSTHRD010 warning? Because I don't reproduce it on your `(DTE)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE));` line. You can check you have all latest nuget packages, or push a repro project somewhere

Comment: @simonmourier Yes that‘s the warning. I used `ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider`, where the wrning was triggered. No matter the warning, the issue with the message should be reproducable. You can create a new `CodeRefactoringProvider` project and use the code I have provided. That‘s all it needs for me to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I didn't say I couldn't reproduce the "gathering" issue. I can't reproduce the thread switch warning, you shouldn't have to add this line, hence my request for a warning repro.

Comment: @SimonMourier As I wrote in attempt 1, removing the line will not solve the issue. I actually can live without switching threads as long asd it's working and I don't face other issues with the solution.